# How can i take data from the onCreate method and put it on the onClick

Tags: android, methods, onclick, oncreate

so basically i created a URL in the onCreate method, and i want to pass it with an intent just when i click on a button. The URL is created but i can't send it to The NeXT activity because it's just in The oncreate method. What should i do ?

Comment: You should probably learn some basic java before going into android.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class variable and assign it the url in the onCreate.

```
   public class MyActiviy extends Activty {
       private URL myURL;

       public static void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
           myURL={insert new URL};
       }
   }
```

Comment: It's kind of crazy but i tricked the app, i just pass it through a textview . and it's work .